# Inconsistent PBKDF2 hashes in Python (django) and Javascript (crypto.js)

Tags: javascript, python, django, encryption, cryptography

Django code:

```
hasher = PBKDF2PasswordHasher()
print hasher.encode(u'qwerty', u'qwerty', iterations=1).split('$')[3]
# T9t/EJXFpPs2Lhca7IVGphTC/OdEloPMHw1UhDnXcyQ=
# hex: 4fdb7f1095c5a4fb362e171aec8546a614c2fce7449683cc1f0d548439d77324
```

Javascript code:

```
var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2('qwerty', 'qwerty', { iterations: 1, keySize: 256/32 });
console.log(key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
// vfBGfG30ahsx6QWs9vrdTGV+wmlg1d5f2+5bFnP5SAU=
// hex: bdf0467c6df46a1b31e905acf6fadd4c657ec26960d5de5fdbee5b1673f94805
```

Comment: are you using the same salt?

Comment: Yes, as you can see above, the salt is `qwerty` for both

Comment: For password hashing you should your at least 10000 iterations. You also should not output more than the native size (20 bytes for SHA1, 32 for SHA256)

Comment: Thanks CodeInChaos, I am actually using this for Key Stretching. I want a 256 bit key for an AES encryption. Also, I agree on the iterations. Was keeping them small for testing purposes. I've set it to a 5000 now since I want it to be fast enough on mobile browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not specifying the right hasher in JS. The default is a SHA1 hasher for CryptoJS and a SHA526 hasher for Django.

```
CryptoJS.PBKDF2('qwerty', 'qwerty', { iterations: 1, keySize: 256/32, hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA256 });
```

fixes the problem